# Some not required when returning Option?

Tags: rust

I am doing the [more combinators](http://rustbyexample.com/error/more_combinators.html) part of "Rust by Example", and decided to go off on my own and see how much effort it is to use `map` instead of `and_then`.

In my attempt, I came across something very strange (it even looks like a compiler error to me). It *looks like* I only need to return a `Food` type when the return type is supposed to be `Option(Food)`

In my opinion, the `cookable` function below should be able to be reduced to a single line:

```
have_ingredients(food).map(|f| can_cook(f))
```

Obviously it can also be the following:

```
have_ingredients(food).and_then(can_cook)
```

Although I don't see the fundamental difference between these two functions, as they both return an `Option<U>`.

I got a weird compiler error when doing so, so I explicitly broke down the match as below -- and looks like the compiler wants to return `Food` even when the return type is `Some(Food)`. What is going on???

```
//! stack.rs
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Food {
    CordonBleu,
    Steak,
    Sushi,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Day {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
}

/// we don't have the ingredients for sushi
fn have_ingredients(food: Food) -> Option<Food> {
    match food {
        Food::Sushi => None,
        _ => Some(food),
    }
}

/// can cook anything but cordon blue
fn can_cook(food: Food) -> Option<Food> {
    match food {
        Food::CordonBlue => None,
        _ => Some(food),
    }
}

/// can be done using map
fn cookable(food: Food) -> Option<Food> {
    match have_ingredients(food).map(|f| can_cook(f)) {
        // Some(food) => food,  // Why is this correct???
        Some(food) => Some(food), // **error: mismatched types:
        None => None,
    }
}

fn eat(food: Food, day: Day) {
    match cookable(food) {
        Some(food) => println!("Yay! On {:?} we eat {:?}", day, food),
        None => println!("Oh no we didn't get to eat on {:?}!", day),
    };
}

fn main() {
    let (cordon_bleu, steak, sushi) = (Food::CordonBleu, Food::Steak, Food::Sushi);
    eat(cordon_bleu, Day::Monday);
    eat(steak, Day::Tuesday);
    eat(sushi, Day::Wednesday);
}
```

Here is the full compiler error from the above program:

```
 ch16_errors git:(master) ✗ rustc stack.rs
stack.rs:38:28: 38:32 error: mismatched types:
 expected `Food`,
    found `core::option::Option<Food>`
(expected enum `Food`,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
stack.rs:38         Some(food) => Some(food),
                                       ^~~~
stack.rs:38:28: 38:32 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
have_ingredients(food).map(|f| can_cook(f))
```

gives an `Option<Option<Food>>`, not an `Option<Food>`, since `map` does not flatten values.

Consider

```
Option<T>::map(Fn(T) -> U)
```

This transforms `Option<T>` to `Option<U>`. Thus letting `T = Food`, `U = Option<Food>` as in `can_cook` gives the instantiation

```
Option<Food>::map(Fn(Food) -> Option<Food>)
```

which gives an `Option<Option<Food>>`.

Thus the `Some(food)` in the match has `food` of type `Option<Food>`.

`and_then` flattens the result type, which is why this does not occur with it.

Comment: I understand now. First of all, the compiler error is saying it expects the *first* food to be type Food. Second of all, the purpose of map is to let you write a short closure that doesn't require you to write Some(T) in it.